# Is this sentence is relative restrictive clause? What does the sentence mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning, phrases, relative-clauses, restrictive-clauses

From [here](https://www.sbnation.com/2017/10/25/16541720/dodgers-world-series-astros-clayton-kershaw-chris-taylor-justin-turner):

> It’s disingenuous to suggest the Dodgers have never had a player come of nowhere quite like Taylor.

I don't understand what "come of" means here. AFAIK, "come of something" means to be the result of something.

Also shouldn't it be "have never had a player **who** comes of..."?

Comment: Suspect it's a typo for come *out* of nowhere; in other words, rapidly rise to prominence from obscurity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. As peterG says, this is a typo for *come out of nowhere*, meaning "emerge unexpectedly".
2. The construction *HAVE + NP + VERB<sup>INF</sup>* means "experience the event of *NP VERBing*". The passive version drops the auxiliary: *HAVE + NP + VERB<sup>PaPpl</sup>*

   - He had a tornado blow his roof off.
   - He had his roof blown off by a tornado.

So the sentence means "It would be disingenuous to pretend that the Dodgers have never experienced the event of a player like Taylor emerging unexpectedly."

Comment: I have always understood the active "have NP V" construction to mean "to get/cause/ask/force/pay someone to do something". https://www.gymglish.com/en/english-grammar/to-have-somebody-do-something   Never have I seen this construction used in the way you described. "I have a friend have a terrier" sounds off. Could you link to some examples online?

Comment: @EddieKalMY Try [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/have); scroll down to "**have** in other verb uses and phrases" and see definition 6 there. But the experience is not necessarily an unpleasant one.

Comment: I get your point. I don't have any issue with the passive construction (with a past participle after the NP). I also know the active construction can mean "to get someone to do". I was actually only wondering about the active construction (the first one you listed), which I thought **only** meant "to get/cause someone to do something." E.g. "I am having a guy fix my roof today"="I will pay a guy to fix my roof today", whereas "I have a friend have a terrier" doesn't mean "I will get a friend to have a terrier".

Comment: @EddieKalMY You can generally distinguish the causative and 'experiential' uses by context: obviously I did not *cause* the tornado to blow my roof off!